# Webscraping an IMDb page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am new to WebScraping/Python and BeautifulSoup and am having difficulty getting my code to work.

I would like to scrape the url: http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate" to get the:

- Name of the celebrity
- Celebrity Image
- Profession
- Best Work

for the ten celebrities on that page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate'

test_url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
readHtml = test_url.read()
test_url.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(readHtml)
# Using it track the number of Actor
count = 0
# Fetching the value present within tag results
person = soup.findChildren('section', 'posters list')
# Changing the person into an iterator
iterperson = iter(person[0].findChildren('a'))

# Finding 'a' in iterperson. Every 'a' tag contains information of a person
for a in iterperson:
    imgSource = a.find('img')['src'].split('._V1.')[0] + '._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg'
    person = a.findChildren('div', 'label')
    title = person[0].find('span', 'title').contents[0]
    ##profession = person[0].find('div', 'detail').contents[0].split(,)
    ##bestWork = person[0].find('div', 'detail').contents[1].split(,)

    print '*******************************IMDB People Born Today***********************************'
    # Printing the S.No of the person
    print 'S.No. --> ',
    count += 1
    print count
    # Printing the title/name of the person
    print 'Title --> ' + title
    # Printing the Image Source of the person
    print 'Image Source --> ', imgSource
    # Printing the Profession of the person
    ##print 'Profession --> ', profession
    # Printing the Best work of the person
    ##print 'Best Work --> ', bestWork
```

Currently nothing is getting printed out.
Also if this to vague could you explain how to do just Name of Celebrity for instance?

Here is the first celebrity's html code if that helps:

```
<section class="posters list">
<h1>March 7</h1>

    <a href="/name/nm0186505/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTA2NjEyMTY4MTVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDQ5NDAzNDc@._V1._CR0,0,1369,2019_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Bryan Cranston</span><div class="detail">Actor, "Ozymandias"</div></div></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, screen scraping is explicitly forbidden by the IMDb ["Conditions of Use"](http://www.imdb.com/conditions):

> Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots,
>   screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on
>   this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

Try *exploring the IMDb JSON API* instead of a web-scraping approach.

---

Your current problem is - the list of people born on the specific date is loaded via a *separate call to the `IMDb` API* and with a *javascript logic* involved.

The easiest option right now would be to switch to [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) browser automation tool. Working example using a *headless `PhantomJS` browser*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate")

# waiting for posters to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
posters = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.posters")))

# extracting the data poster by poster
for a in posters.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.poster'):
    img = a.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src').split('._V1.')[0] + '._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg'

    person = a.find_element_by_css_selector('div.detail').text
    title = a.find_element_by_css_selector('span.title').text

    print img, person, title
```

Prints:

```
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTA2NjEyMTY4MTVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDQ5NDAzNDc@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actor, "Ozymandias" Bryan Cranston
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjUxNjcxMjE4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk4NjA2MzE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actress, "Karla" Laura Prepon
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4MzM1MDAwMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU4NzQwMw@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actress, "The Mummy" Rachel Weisz
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0Mjg0NzE2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDE1MTkxMw@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actor, "Jarhead" Peter Sarsgaard
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMyOTYzODQ5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjE3MDgzMQ@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actress, "Blades of Glory" Jenna Fischer
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzE2OTAwNzM0Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzE1MDg0Mw@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actress, "Tangled" Donna Murphy
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI0OTMzMzE0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI1MzYyMQ@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actor, "How the Grinch Stole Christmas" T.J. Thyne
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzczODkyNzY4OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU0NjQzMQ@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actor, "Home Alone" John Heard
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MjU2MzA2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTIxMjc4MjE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Actress, "Beerfest" Audrey Marie Anderson
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQyOTc5NzA0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwODQ2MjYz._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg Producer, "Kick-Ass" Matthew Vaughn
```

Comment: Thankyou, would it be not possible to do it in beautifulsoup?

Comment: @PatrickLee yes, if you want, you can pass the page_source from `selenium` to `BeautifulSoup`: once the posters are loaded do: `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)`.

Comment: I will make sure  to try selenium out, but unfortunately for this problem I need to use BeautifulSoup by itself as it is the tool I am expected to use :(

Comment: @PatrickLee well, in this case you can still use `BeautifulSoup` for an HTML parsing part, but `selenium` is the safest and easiest way to get the HTML source as you would see in the browser.

Comment: I am able to webscrape the films from this page http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014%27 using BeautifulSoup using similar code.

Comment: Ok I understand Alexce I will try that

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same assignment. URLlib library loads static content of web URL. Use selenium to get complete html which includes dynamic content too. If you use urllib2 library, generated html would be

```
<span class="loading"></span>
```

Hope it helps.