# beautifulsoup imdb borntoday page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the information from imdb borntoday page?

I have looked at this question, and it is not answered there.

[Webscraping an IMDb page using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912004/webscraping-an-imdb-page-using-beautifulsoup/41734087#41734087)

I have tried the below code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_url='https://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate'

url=urllib2.urlopen(test_url)
html_text=url.read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text)

poster=soup.find('a','poster')
print poster
print type(poster)
print type(soup)
print html_text
url.close()
```

I am trying to find atleast one element before keeping the logic in loop.

HTML page content is given below. Output poster and type(poster) is giving me None. Please help me where I am missing in the code.

```
<section class="posters list">
<h1>January 18</h1>

<a href="/name/nm0000126/" class="poster "><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0MDU1OTEyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjI0MTk2MDE@._V1._CR0,0,419,618_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Kevin Costner</span><div class="detail">Actor, "Dances with Wolves"</div></div></a>
```

Thanks,
Phani.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Check the answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want only the top 10 actors. I am facing some issues to import dryscrape but seems like the code you posted should work. Also I understood that dynamic content html extraction is not possible with beautifulsoup.  Thanks for your time in responding.

Answer (score 0):

This will give actors only on the first page. If you want all the actors/actresses you will have to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or some other library.

Verify if date is `0d` or `d` when it's single digit.

You can try something like this with [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for actors/actresses on the first page:

```
import re
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

todays_date = datetime.today().strftime('%B %d')

test_url='https://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate'
sess = dryscrape.Session()
sess.visit(test_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(sess.body())
l1 = [a.strip() for a in soup.text.split('\n') if a.strip()]
idx = l1.index(todays_date)
l2 = [a.strip() for a in l1[idx+1].split(',')]
l3 = [re.sub(r'.*"', '',a) for a in l2]
l4 = [re.sub(r'(Actor|Actress)', r' \1', a) for a in l3]
l5 = [a for a in l4 if a.endswith('Actor') or a.endswith('Actress')]
l5
```

Output:

```
[u'Logan Lerman Actor',
 u'Katey Sagal Actress',
 u'Drea de Matteo Actress',
 u'Tippi Hedren Actress',
 u'Jodie Sweetin Actress',
 u'Elizabeth Tulloch Actress',
 u'Marsha Thomason Actress',
 u'Erin Sanders Actress',
 u'Mickey Sumner Actress']
```